# ASP.Net Web Api Get Reques By Selected Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a database with primary key Auto increment id when a send a get request to web api I want to filter datas by specified columns equals something.
When i tried this in SSMS its working
`Select top 1000 from [dbo.][ogrencisonuclar] where kullaniciid='1'`
But How can i do this request by web api ? I'm using entity framework. When I requested datas filtering by primary key id not kullaniciid..

This is code on my web api

```
 public ogrencisonuclar Get(int ID)
        {
            using (denemetabloEntities entities = new denemetabloEntities())
            {

                ogrencisonuclar sonuc = entities.ogrencisonuclar.Find(ID);
                return sonuc;
            }
        }
```

This is the code on Xamarin to request datas by kullaniciid;

```
var client1 = new RestClient("http://mikrontasarim.somee.com/api/ogrencisonuclar/Get/" + kullid);
            client1.Timeout = -1;
            var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            var response1 = client1.Execute<List<Models.sonucagecismodeli>>(request1);
            List<Models.sonucagecismodeli> events = response1.Data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` always queries by the PK.  You can use a LINQ query to query on other parameters

```
ogrencisonuclar sonuc = entities.ogrencisonuclar.Where(x => x.kullaniciid == ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

to fetch all matching rows

```
ogrencisonuclar sonuc = entities.ogrencisonuclar.Where(x => x.kullaniciid == ID).ToList();
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/)

Comment: Okay but it's fetching only 1 data there are few datas which kullaniciid=1

Comment: It's give an error like this ..
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestApp1.ogrencisonuclar>' to 'TestApp1.ogrencisonuclar'

Comment: that's because your `Get` method signature only returns one `ogrencisonuclar` instead of a List

Comment: Okay I changed it to public list<ogrencisonuclar> and it works perfectly thanks a lot :)